# Can Ruby handle large hash objects

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to compare two hashes. Each can have more than 20,000 objects.

I have the following questions:

- Can Ruby handle such a large amount of objects?
- Will comparing these two hashes take a lot of time?
- Can indexing be applied to reduce enumerations?

Comment: i think it's not about rails, it's about ruby.

Comment: You will need to be more specific about your `objects` term. Are you comparing simple string/integers... Comparing a simple hash of string and integers of 20 000+ entries is instant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails is a framework and has little to do with object comparison. Ruby is certainly capable of comparing 20,000 objects, assuming they fit well into memory or you are comparing them in a batch process that limits how many are instantiated at any time.

If you are are talking about comparing 20,000 `ActiveRecord` objects *in-memory* you will probably run out of memory and may experience pretty slow results even if you don't. ActiveRecord is pretty heavy-weight and not the best tool for working with large numbers of objects. However, I don't know what these 20,000 objects are or exactly how you are comparing them, so maybe they don't have to all be in-memory simultaneously and a batch process could complete this in a time frame you find acceptable.

If these are simple objects in a simple ruby hash you can certainly iterate through them pretty quickly (though what is **fast** is completely dependent on what this is *for*). If your comparison logic is pretty simple it shouldn't be too time consuming, assuming each object in your first hash is compared to a single corresponding object in the second hash. If every object in hash 1 is compared to each of the 20,000 in hash 2 then your total comparisons (20,000 * 20,0000) are much larger and this might not be as fast as you need.

Comment: ya its fast enough,infact even better.

Answer (score 4):

The hashes themselves are fast and not bound to low limits. E.g. this does not even take a millisecond here (Ruby 1.9.2 on Windows):

```
irb(main):008:0> hash1 = (0...20000).inject({}) { | r, i | r[rand(100)*100000 + i] = rand; r } ; 23
=> 23
irb(main):009:0> hash2 = (0...20000).inject({}) { | r, i | r[rand(100)*100000 + i] = rand; r } ; 23
=> 23
irb(main):010:0> hash3 = hash1.dup ; 23
=> 23
irb(main):011:0> hash1 == hash2
=> false
irb(main):012:0> hash1 == hash3
=> true
```

Everything else depends on what you are stuffing into the hashes.